# Extracting the Contents of tar archive to parent directory issue resulting in creation of sub directories

Tags: tar, mv, dot-files

I have a Tar file: `testwebsite.tar`

I've placed it in the directory I would like to extract its contents  to on my Web server which is mytestdirectory

I run this command via PuTTY: `tar -xvf testwebsite.tar`

Which results in the content being extracted but in this format:

```
mytestdirectory/srv/test/www.testwebsite.com/
```

All of the files I would like have appear in `mytestdirectory` are contained in the `www.testwebsite.com` sub directory.

Is there a way I can move all of the content within this sub directory to the parent directory using the `mv` command?

I was looking around and tried a few answers, one being to run this command from within the sub directory:

```
mv * .[^.]* ..
```

But that resulted in this message being shown:

```
mv: cannot stat `*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `.[^.]*': No such file or directory
```

Could someone please help me on this issue, I'm basically trying to move all of the content  (including hidden files) from the sub directory www.testwebsite.com to the parent directory mytestdirectory.

Comment: "Related" - [tar – extract discarding directory structure](http://superuser.com/q/71846/354511).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `--strip-components` option of tar; that's because the paths you don't need are contained in the tar archive.

So for instance if the tar contains this: `srv/test/www.testwebsite.com/index.html` and you want to obtain this `mytestdirectory/index.html`, you need

```
$ cd /path/to/mytestdirectory
$ tar xf testwebsite.tar --strip-components=3
```

If you use the verbose command, you will still set the full original filenames, so you can also add the `--show-transformed` argument to list the modified paths:

```
$ tar tfz workspace.tar.gz --strip-components=2 workspace/project
-rw-rw-r-- guido/guido   11134 2009-01-22 23:21 workspace/project/aaa
-rw-rw-r-- guido/guido   11134 2009-01-22 23:21 workspace/project/bbb
[... list continues ...]
$ tar tfz workspace.tar.gz --strip-components=2 --show-transformed workspace/project
-rw-rw-r-- guido/guido   11134 2009-01-22 23:21 aaa
-rw-rw-r-- guido/guido   11134 2009-01-22 23:21 bbb
[ ... and so on ...]
```

To fix your situation with `mv`, that would be:

```
# cd /path/to/mytestdirectory 
# mv srv/test/www.testwebsite.com/* .
```

For taking care of hidden files, one soution will be this:

```
# shopt -s dotglob
```

executed before the above commands, to the glob also match dotfiles; or even better, delete your current target directory, then move and rename the one you want to copy:

```
[ delete or rename current /path/to/mytestdirectory ]
# cd /path/to
# mv srv/test/www.testwebsite.com/ mytestdirectory/
# rmdir srv/test/ srv/
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, but when I try the above command `$ tar xf testwebsite.tar --strip-components=4 ` I get a whole load of images being placed in the root directory as opposed to all of the files?

Comment: the `4` in the answer was just en example, it depends on how many path components you need to strip away: I guess in your tar archive all file paths start with `srv/test/www.testwebsite.com/`, if that's the case you should execute the tar command inside `mytestdirectory` and use `--strip-components=3`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED! You've saved me so much pain and headaches. I'm a novice when it comes to Linux and get by with just about as much as I can. This answer was so so helpful